# Именовать изображения. python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть, к примеру, 250+ небольших изображений. На них написано что они такое. К примеру возьмем случайные фрукты. Я столкнулся с проблемой: мне нужно просмотреть 250 изображений, записать их имя **на русском** (именно вручную; скрипты распознавания текста меня не устраивают точностью), записать путь к их файлу и группировать все файлы по именам. В конечном итоге должен получится такой JSON конфиг (очень примерно): {Яблоко:["файл_1.png", "файл_185.png", ..], ..}.

Как вы уже могли понять, это неадекватно делать все вручную.

Уже пробовал:

1. многопоточность: 1 поток показывает изображения (cv2.imshow), в другом я ввожу имя. Не получилось. Было много разных ошибок...
2. ввод имени через cv2.waitKey. Не получилось. Он крайне не хотел распознавать юникод. Как то попробовал "вроде рабочий" скрипт, так то, что он мне накалякал в файл ерунду а не юникод я узнал после 250 картинки....
3. ввод имени через pygame. Pygame еще хуже поддерживает юникод. Я не нашел способа написать ЖЭЪХЮБ, кавычки и требуемого мне тире.*

Я немного в отчаянии. Что поможет реализовать мою задачу? **Повторюсь. Мне нужен ввод кирилицы и я должен видеть изображение для этого.**

Comment: Раз руками заполнять, то скачайте все картинки в файл и там руками напишите. Кст, в имя файла нельзя кавычки записать. Если вы хотели в GUI это сделать, то я бы это через pyqt5, странно, что в pygame есть проблемы с юникодом, думаю, вы что-то неправильное делали :)

Comment: Возможно я не так выразился. У меня есть картинки с надписью "яблоко". Мне нужно записать в json файл "яблоко" (как ключ) и присвоить ему значение списка с изображениями, на которых написано яблоко. Файлы у меня преимущественно пронумерованые. То есть "1.png" .. "250.png".

Comment: Нейронку обучаете? :) Т.е. вы сделали программу, что открывает те картинки и вы по содержимому картинки пишите к какому ключу относится и файл той картинки будет добавлен в список json по ключу? Но у вас что-то не получается :/

Comment: Нет нет. Вы угадали, но свою задачу я поставил крайне абстрактно. Есть большое изображение список. Эти маленькие изображения - его возможные члены. Их ищем cv2.matchTemplate. Но если на 1 локацию претендуют 2 элемента, то тут обучается нейронка определять один из этих элементов. Так сказать устраняем конфликтные срабатывания. Моя проблема в пальцекровимазохизманестрадании. Эти маленькие изображения должны иметь значения (то есть имена). И их я не могу нормально добавить в json файл ассоциирующий их имя с картинкой. Воот.. pyqt5 вроде подходит. Не уверен. С библиотекой только буду знакомится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Накидал прототип](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/5aa5c656b735d1b8303f167ce3d3b1ca8dfc5c3b/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/show_images_and_append_their_to_json) программы:

- Установка в консоли: `pip install pyqt5`
- Есть папка с картинками: `images`
- При запуске через `glob` загружается список картинок
- Указывая значения в ключ и нажимая *Добавить картинку* программа добавит ее в словарь, где ключом будет введенное значение, а значением список файлов картинок

Пример:

```
import json
import glob

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QDockWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QPlainTextEdit
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self._current_index_image = 0
        self._images = glob.glob('images/*.png')
        self._data = dict()

        self.label_image = QLabel()
        self.label_image.setFixedSize(400, 400)
        self.label_image.setScaledContents(True)

        self.line_edit_key = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_key.setPlaceholderText('Введите ключ картинки...')

        self.button_add_file_name = QPushButton('Добавить картинку')
        self.button_add_file_name.clicked.connect(self._on_add_file_name)

        self.button_prev = QPushButton('Предыдущая картинка')
        self.button_prev.clicked.connect(self.load_prev_image)

        self.button_next = QPushButton('Следующая картинка')
        self.button_next.clicked.connect(self.load_next_image)

        layout_control = QHBoxLayout()
        layout_control.addWidget(QLabel('Ключ:'))
        layout_control.addWidget(self.line_edit_key)
        layout_control.addWidget(self.button_add_file_name)

        layout_control_2 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout_control_2.addWidget(self.button_prev)
        layout_control_2.addWidget(self.button_next)

        self.pl_text_json = QPlainTextEdit()

        self._dock_widget = QDockWidget('JSON')
        self._dock_widget.setWidget(self.pl_text_json)

        self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self._dock_widget)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.label_image)
        main_layout.addLayout(layout_control)
        main_layout.addLayout(layout_control_2)
        main_layout.addStretch()

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.load_current_image()

    def get_current_image_file_name(self):
        return self._images[self._current_index_image]

    def load_prev_image(self):
        self._current_index_image -= 1
        if self._current_index_image < 0:
            self._current_index_image = 0

        self.load_current_image()

    def load_next_image(self):
        self._current_index_image += 1
        if self._current_index_image >= len(self._images):
            self._current_index_image = len(self._images) - 1

        self.load_current_image()

    def load_current_image(self):
        self.update_states()

        file_name = self.get_current_image_file_name()

        pixmap = QPixmap()
        pixmap.load(file_name)
        self.label_image.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def _on_add_file_name(self):
        key = self.line_edit_key.text()
        file_name = self.get_current_image_file_name()

        if key not in self._data:
            self._data[key] = []

        if file_name not in self._data[key]:
            self._data[key].append(file_name)

        self.pl_text_json.setPlainText(
            json.dumps(self._data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
        )

    def update_states(self):
        file_name = self.get_current_image_file_name()
        self.setWindowTitle(f'{self._current_index_image + 1} / {len(self._images)} : {file_name}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]